# How do I enable diagnostics in Unity Container v5.x

Tags: unity-container

None of the methods described here works:
https://unitycontainer.github.io/tutorials/diagnostic.html

I've tried:
`var container = new UnityContainer().EnableDiagnostic();`

and

`var container = new UnityContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic());`

I have a bad registration somewhere and it does `ThrowingBuildUp`